# TCPDF set bottom margin zero

Tags: php, pdf, margin, tcpdf

I am creating pdf using TCPDF in php,I need to include my data into pdf without bottom margines,The data will be included at the end of the page.

```
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(14);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(6);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', '9');
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
```

I am using the above code.Anyone know how to remove margin space from pdf using tcpdf?

Comment: possibly attach output that you received

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Margin that you are seeing is due to pageBreak margin

Add this `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);`
definitely remove margin from bottom

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It removes the bottom space and right space that setMargin(0,0,0,false); doesn't remove.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 $pdf->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);
```

read this... you will get some idea....http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_022.phps